# How do I specify a key file when using Dataflow?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

Within my Dataflow pipeline, I have a function that creates a Cloud Storage client.  Instead of my VMs automatically using the default credentials, I would like to specify a key file.

I believe the way to do that is

```
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json([path to local file])
```

However, I'm not sure where to put my json file so that my pipeline function has access to it.  Where should I upload my json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow uses [controller service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#controller-service-account) to create and manage resources when executing a pipeline

If you want to create and use resources with fine-grained access and control, you can use a service account from your job's project as the user-managed controller service account.

Use the --serviceAccount option and specify your service account when you run your pipeline job:

**--serviceAccount=my-service-account-name@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com**